# Delphi Indy FTP EIdReplyRFCError

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

i connect to my FTP Server like this:

```
with ftp do
begin
try
  Username := 'user';
  Password := 'password';
  Port := 990;
  Host := 'host';
  Passive := true;
  IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(ftp);
  UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
  ConnectTimeout := 10000;
  TransferTimeout := 120000;
  ListenTimeout := 60000;
  ReadTimeout := 120000;
  TransferType := ftBinary;
  Connect;
except
  ExitCode := 404;
  BringOnTop;
  Application.MessageBox('Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden', 'Achtung', MB_OK or MB_ICONERROR);
  Halt;
end;
end;
```

After the Connect, i go to my Dir

```
ftp.ChangeDir(fDir);
```

And then get my file:

```
ftp.Get(fServer_file.name,fLokal_file.name,true);
```

All of this works, if the Network is not under heavy load.
But as soon, as i got a heavy network load, i got an EIdReplyRFCError Exception at the ftp.Get

Here is a FTP Log with the Error

```
Stat Verbunden.
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 220 FTP Server ready.<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: HOST host<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 504 host: Unknown hostname provided<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: AUTH TLS<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 234 AUTH TLS successful<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: USER user<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 331 Password required for user<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: PASS pass<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 230 Zugriff gewaehrt fuer user<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: FEAT<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 211-Features:<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  AUTH TLS<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  CCC<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  CLNT<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  EPRT<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  EPSV<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  HOST<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  LANG zh-TW;en-US;ko-KR;zh-CN;ja-JP;es-ES;it-IT;bg-BG;fr-FR;ru-RU<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  MDTM<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  MFMT<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.groupname*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;UNIX.ownername*;<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  PBSZ<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  PROT<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  REST STREAM<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  SITE COPY<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  SITE MKDIR<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  SITE RMDIR<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  SITE SYMLINK<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  SITE UTIME<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  SIZE<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  SSCN<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  TVFS<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29:  UTF8<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 211 End<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: CLNT Indy 10.6.2.5298<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 200 OK<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: TYPE I<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 200 Type set to I<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: SYST<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 215 UNIX Type: L8<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: TYPE I<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 200 Type set to I<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: CWD TGS<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 250 CWD command successful<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: MDTM exsample.exe<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 213 20170627135708<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:29: SIZE exsample.exe<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:29: 213 7069184<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:31: PBSZ 0<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:31: 200 PBSZ 0 successful<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:31: PROT C<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:31: 200 Protection set to Clear<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:31: PASV<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:31: 227 Entering Passive Mode (109,237,134,44,254,124).<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:31: RETR exsample.exe<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:31: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for exsample.exe (7069184 bytes)<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:41: 426 Transfer aborted. Unterbrechung während des Betriebssystemaufrufs<EOL>
Ges 28.06.2017 10:21:55: QUIT<EOL>
Erh 28.06.2017 10:21:55: 221 Goodbye.<EOL>
Stat Verbindung getrennt.
Stat Verbindung getrennt.
```

This Script is from FileZilla under heavy Networkload:

```
Befehl: PASV
Antwort:    227 Entering Passive Mode (109,237,134,44,254,100).
Befehl: RETR example.exe
Antwort:    150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for example.exe (7069184 bytes)
Antwort:    426 Transfer aborted. Unterbrechung während des Betriebssystemaufrufs
Fehler: Dateitransfer fehlgeschlagen nach Übertragung von 2.179.040 Bytes in 92 Sekunden
Status: Starte Download von /TGS/example.exe
Befehl: PASV
Antwort:    227 Entering Passive Mode (109,237,134,44,254,159).
Befehl: REST 2179040
Antwort:    350 Restarting at 2179040. Send STORE or RETRIEVE to initiate transfer
Befehl: RETR example.exe
Antwort:    150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for example.exe (4890144 bytes)
Antwort:    426 Transfer aborted. Unterbrechung während des Betriebssystemaufrufs
Fehler: Dateitransfer fehlgeschlagen nach Übertragung von 174.760 Bytes in 13 Sekunden
Status: Starte Download von /TGS/example.exe
Befehl: PASV
Antwort:    227 Entering Passive Mode (109,237,134,44,254,57).
Befehl: REST 2353800
Antwort:    350 Restarting at 2353800. Send STORE or RETRIEVE to initiate transfer
Befehl: RETR example.exe
Antwort:    150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for example.exe (4715384 bytes)
Antwort:    426 Transfer aborted. Unterbrechung während des Betriebssystemaufrufs
Fehler: Dateitransfer fehlgeschlagen nach Übertragung von 2.271.880 Bytes in 89 Sekunden
Status: Starte Download von /TGS/example.exe
Befehl: PASV
Antwort:    227 Entering Passive Mode (109,237,134,44,254,65).
Befehl: REST 4625680
Antwort:    350 Restarting at 4625680. Send STORE or RETRIEVE to initiate transfer
Befehl: RETR example.exe
Antwort:    150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for example.exe (2443504 bytes)
Antwort:    226 Transfer complete
Status: Dateitransfer erfolgreich, 2.443.504 Bytes in 9 Sekunden übertragen
Status: Verbindung zum Server getrennt
Fehler: Verbindung vom Server geschlossen
```

The Exception says: "Transfer aborted. Unterbrechung während des Betriebssystemaufrufs" <-- Trans: Interruption during the Operatingssystemcall

Comment: Ok, so what can we do? Could you describe that exception in details?

Comment: `EIdReplyRFCError` is only raised when the FTP server sends back an error in response to a command. Network load does not affect error handling, so something else is going on. Which command is raising the error? What are the actual error code and error message that are being reported in the exception?

Comment: I edited the Answer with the asked Informations

Comment: The error is on the server side, not in `TIdFTP`. The server is getting a system error while transferring a file and is aborting the transfer on its end. There is nothing you can do about that on the client side. The FileZilla log contains the same server error. FileZilla is simply using the `REST` command to have a new transfer pick up where the previous transfer left off, repeating multiple times as needed until the file is fully transferred. You can do the same thing with `TIdFTP.Get()` by calling it with `AResume=true` and `ACanOverwrite=false` after the initial transfer fails.